# glade keyboard (escape, arrows) accelerators

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, glade, acceleratorkey

I am using glade along with language C to develop a GUI. I am able to map all the number keys and letter keys from keyboard to glade buttons as accelerators. However, i cannot map the following buttons: ESC, Up, Down, Left, Right arrows.

In glade when i type in the accelerator field up, down, left, right or esc nothing is stored. But if i type them in holding the CTRL it stores them as primary button.

[image]

Even in .glade file the keys are stored as they are supposed to be by working alone, but they only function when i hold also the CTRL.

```
<object class="GtkButton" id="button_left_roll">
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">True</property>
  <property name="receives_default">True</property>
  <property name="image">image19</property>
  <property name="always_show_image">True</property>
  <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button_left_roll_clicked" swapped="no"/>
  <accelerator key="Left" signal="clicked" modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"/>
</object>
```

How can i use them without holding down the CTRL key?

Comment: `modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK"` says they are not supposed to work without `ctrl` key pressed. What happens if you just remove this part?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev thank you very much, this was the problem, but removing it caused the gui to not show. But i searched for modifiers and found a workaround

Answer (score 0):

What actually causes the problem is:
modifiers="GDK_CONTROL_MASK".
So what worked for me is:
setting GDK_CONTROL_MASK to GDK_LOCK_MASK.

Comment: `GDK_LOCK_MASK a Lock key (depending on the modifier mapping of the X server this may either be CapsLock or ShiftLock).` I'm pretty sure it's a kludge, not a solution.

Comment: yes i agree, but i tried all the other options for modifiers and nothing worked for me